# How do I solve the following inhomogeneous DE: $y'(x)=\begin{pmatrix}-2x^{-1} & x^{-1} \\3x^{-1} & 0 \\\end{pmatrix}y(x)+\binom{x^2}{3x^2}$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

How do I show that $Y(x)=\begin{pmatrix}x^{-3} & x \\-x^{-3} & 3x \\\end{pmatrix}$ is the fundamental solution.

I've been trying to derive Y(x) (i.e. $Y'(x) = y(x)$) which results, if I'm not mistaken in a 2×2
 matrix,  which in turn is multiplied with the 2×2 matrix left of $y(x)$ (i.e. $\begin{pmatrix}-2x^{-1} & x^{-1} \\3x^{-1} & 0 \\\end{pmatrix}y(x)$), which would result in a new 2×2 matrix. I don't understand how a 2×2 matrix + a 2-Dim vector would result in the equation needed. So I'm clearly approaching this the wrong way.

I haven't got any experience with DE's that involve Matrices, so I'm looking for some guidance. What are the steps I need to take to prove this relationship?

Comment: Void:  That's exactly the kind of context/information we hope to get from askers, along with the clear statement of the question.  Why don't you copy and paste the comment immediately above my comment here, into your post?

Comment: Note the matrix equation.  In order to sum the last $2\times 1$ vector at the end of the matrix equation, we need to have that $y(x)$ is $2\times 1$..

Comment: Let's label the $2 \times 2$ matrix you've written as $A$, now, we have $y'(x) = A_{2\times 2}\cdot y(x) +\begin{matrix} x^2\\ 3x^2 \end{matrix}$. $A\cdot y(x)$ must be of dimension $2\times 1$, otherwise addition with the final "vector" won't be defined.    Note that $A_{2\times 2}\cdot y(x)_{2\times 1} = (A\cdot y(x))_{2\times 1}$  So y(x) must be a $2\times 1$ vector.

Comment: Ok, I see! So I could technically write $y(x) = \binom{y_1}{y_2}$ and solve for $y_1$ and $y_2$?

Comment: Yes you can!! ${}{}$

Answer (score 0):

As always, $y=y_p+y_h$.

Assume that $y_p = cx^3$, where $c$ is a 2x1 vector. Then,
$$3cx^2 = (Ac+b)x^2,$$where $$A=\begin{pmatrix} -2&1 \\ 3&0\end{pmatrix}$$ and $$b=\begin{pmatrix}1\\3\end{pmatrix}$$

Thus,
$$(A-3I)c = -b$$
The result is,
$$c=\frac{1}{12}\begin{pmatrix} 3&1 \\ 3&5\end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix}1\\3\end{pmatrix}={1\over2}\begin{pmatrix}1\\3\end{pmatrix}$$

To solve $y_h$, note that $xy_h' - Ay_h=0$. Assume $y_h = r_nx^n$. Then,
$$nr_nx^{n}-Ar_nx^{n}=0.$$ So, $$(A-nI)r_n = 0.$$
In other words, $r_n = 0$ as long as $A-nI$ is invertible. Equivalently, $det(A-nI)=n(2+n)-3\neq0$ so long as $n\neq {1, -3}$.

In each of the two cases, you solve a 2x2 system to find the $r_n$ that nulls $A-nI$.

For $n=1$, 
$$r_1 = \alpha_1\begin{pmatrix}1\\3\end{pmatrix}$$
For $n=-3$,
$$r_{-3}=\alpha_2\begin{pmatrix}1\\-1\end{pmatrix}$$

Thus,
$$y=\alpha_1\begin{pmatrix}1\\3\end{pmatrix}x + \alpha_2\begin{pmatrix}1\\-1\end{pmatrix}x^{-3} + {1\over2}\begin{pmatrix}1\\3\end{pmatrix}x^3$$